# How can I output a static link/txt file?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Right now I have a file cse_newsletter.cfm that look like this(kind of).

```
<html>
.......
<cfquery>
select ....
</cfquery>

<cfquery>
select ....
</cfquery>
.......
 <cfoutput>
      <h1>Starburst Star Award</h1>
     <h3>Winner: Department- #highest_dept_name_average#</h3>
     <h3>Average:  #hihest_dept_average# </h3>
     <h4>Runner-up: Department- #highest_dept_name_runnerup# </h4>
     <h4> Average: #highest_dept_name_average_runnerup# </h4>
  </cfoutput>
</html>
```

This does no updates/insert to a table only gets data from the past months. 
What it it does it gives me the data from the past month and output for example the highest_dept_average. 
The link is in cse_exeoffice.cfm `<a href="cse_execoffice_newsletter.cfm">Newsletter</a><br>`.

So every first of the Month it will generate the data from the past month( but it wont save the data in a txt or click on a link )
I would like to create a way that everytime I click on a submit button it will generate the data in cse_newsletter.cfm, and it will create a link or txt file(show the link in cse_exeoffice.cfm).

Maybe there is a better way that I can generate the data and give me the output I want without a submit button.Even better would be without a submit button, because im not submitting a form.

Any help or advice on how to approach this would be helpful. I have try a test with `<cffile action="write"..>` but that would just overwrite the txt file every time I run it.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing, but I will try to help you.
If I understood you, every time someone clicks on link you want to download some content in txt file ?

Comment: You need to include in the file path something that reflects the difference in the data from month to month, eg have `data_yymm.txt` where `yymm` is the year/month. That way it doesn't matter if you re-run the process within a given month (the data will be the same, so doesn't matter if it overwrites), but each new month will have a different file name.

Comment: It's not clear why you need to create files at all.  If the newsletter always displays data from the previous month, why is that not good enough?

Comment: @adamcameron Are you saying include a filepath in cffile action="write"?

Comment: @danbracuk I would actually would like to stay away from creating a new file, creating a link would be better

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a way to select a past month and then use it to generate the report you need. You would need to adjust what you're currently using to get the previous month's report to accept a month as input and then return the report for that month.

That way even if a particular month is several months back, you can still get the report, and you get to save disc space as you will be generating your reports on-the-fly.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure anybody got the problem exactly, according to my guess, you want to run report just once and then it be available to you always through a txt or htm file whose link is also available to you and you can see that repory by clicking on the link. I am not giving you exact code, but just a ballpark how you can achieve something like this.
Let us say you create a HTM file when you run it first time. You can give this file a proper name which could be identified by the system as Adam Cameron mentioned something like     data_yymm.htm 

1) Now in your cse_exeoffice.cfm you can do a FileExists check for data_yymm.htm if it exists, link to that otherwise link it to cse_execoffice_newsletter.cfm

2) In cse_execoffice_newsletter.cfm, you do not pour your content directly on the screen, instead save it in variable with CFSaveContent like
    <cfsavecontent variable="variables.filecontent">

## Starburst Star Award

#### Winner: Department- #highest_dept_name_average#

#### Average:  #hihest_dept_average#

Runner-up: Department- #highest_dept_name_runnerup# 
      Average: #highest_dept_name_average_runnerup# 
   
    </cfsavecontent>

3) Now you can display this variables.filecontent as well as write it to htm file.